# Dapper mapping multiple joins to single object returning no records

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, dapper

Im trying to use Dapper in an ASP.Net Core application to map multiple tables to one object with other objects as its properties.

My tables are as follows (just basic summary):

- user table
- address table (no user ids stored in this table, this table is just address records)
- address_type table (lookup table)
- phone_number table (no user ids stored in this table, this table is
  just phone records)
- phone_number _type table (lookup table)
- user_has_address table - this table has a user_id, address_id and address_type_id
- user_has_phone_number table - this table has a
  user_id, phone_number _id and phone_number _type_id

Basically whats happening is results get returned fine if all the users have no address or phone records or if only the first user in the list has address/phone records. What I want is if a user has an address/phone number then that dictionary is populated, otherwise I still want all the user info but that address/phone number dictionary will be empty.

My objects look like the following:

```
public class User
{
  public uint id { get; set; }
  public DateTime modified_date { get; set; }
  public uint modified_by { get; set; }
  public string user_name { get; set; }
  public uint company_code { get; set; }
  public string email { get; set; }
  public bool active { get; set; }
  public string first_name { get; set; }
  public string last_name { get; set; }        
  public Dictionary<uint, Address.Address> addresses { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<uint, Address.PhoneNumber> phone_numbers { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
  public uint address_id { get; set; }
  public AddressType address_type { get; set; }
  public string address_line1 { get; set; }
  public string address_line2 { get; set; }
  public string address_line3 { get; set; }
  public string city { get; set; }
  public string state { get; set; }
  public string country_code { get; set; }
  public string postal_code { get; set; }
  public sbyte is_po_box { get; set; }
}

public class AddressType
{
  public uint id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
  public uint id { get; set; }
  public PhoneNumberType phone_number_type { get; set; }
  public string phone_number { get; set; }
  public string phone_ext { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumberType
{
  public uint id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my function where I try to use Dapper to map to the User class:

```
public List<User> GetUsersByStatus(uint companyCode, string status)
    {           
        if (companyCode == 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("companyID", "The Company ID cannot be 0.");

        List<User> Users = new List<User>();
        try
        {
            string sql = @"SELECT u.*, ad.*, adt.*, p.*, pt.* 
                FROM master.user u
                LEFT JOIN master.user_has_address AS uha ON uha.user_id = u.id                    
                LEFT JOIN master.address AS ad ON ad.id = uha.address_id
                LEFT JOIN master.lookup_address_type adt ON adt.id = uha.address_type_id
                LEFT JOIN master.user_has_phone_number AS uhp ON uhp.user_id = u.id                    
                LEFT JOIN master.phone_number AS p ON p.id = uhp.phone_number_id
                LEFT JOIN master.lookup_phone_number_type pt ON pt.id = uhp.phone_number_type_id
                WHERE u.company_code = " + companyCode;

            switch (status)
            {
                case "1":
                    // Active Status.
                    sql = sql + " AND (u.active = TRUE)";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    // Retired Status.
                    sql = sql + " AND (u.active = FALSE)";
                    break;
            }
            sql = sql + " ORDER BY u.user_name";

            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var userDictionary = new Dictionary<uint, User>();

                conn.Query<User, Address, AddressType, PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberType, User>(sql, (u, ad, adt, p, pt) =>
                {
                    User user;
                    if (!userDictionary.TryGetValue(u.id, out user))
                        userDictionary.Add(u.id, user = u);

                    if (ad != null && adt != null)
                    {
                        Address address = ad;
                        address.address_type = new AddressType() { id = adt.id, name = adt.name };

                        if (user.addresses == null)
                            user.addresses = new Dictionary<uint, Address>();

                        if (!user.addresses.ContainsKey(adt.id))
                            user.addresses.Add(adt.id, address);
                    }

                    if (p != null && pt != null)
                    {
                        PhoneNumber phone = p;
                        phone.phone_number_type = new PhoneNumberType() { id = pt.id, name = pt.name };

                        if (user.phone_numbers == null)
                            user.phone_numbers = new Dictionary<uint, PhoneNumber>();

                        if (!user.phone_numbers.ContainsKey(pt.id))
                            user.phone_numbers.Add(pt.id, phone);
                    }

                    return user;
                },
                splitOn: "id,id,id,id").AsQueryable();

                Users = userDictionary.Values.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //TO DO: log exception
        }

        return Users;
    }
```

I've tried tracing through it and in cases where the 3rd user (for example) has address/phone records, it seems to grab the first 2 users fine but then jump right out of the query portion when it gets to the record with address/phone numbers and then it returns an empty Users list.

Does anyone have any idea what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the main issue was the fact that I left the address_id parameter in the Address class named the way it was, it should ahve been just 'id'. I updated that and it works now, I did also update my code according to Palle Due's suggestion so that may have contributed as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the solution, but I have a problem with this code:

```
User user;
if (!userDictionary.TryGetValue(u.id, out user))
    userDictionary.Add(u.id, user = u);
```

Remember that u is parameter of the lambda, and will be changed during execution. I would do this:

```
User user;
if (!userDictionary.TryGetValue(u.id, out user))
{
    user = new User(u); // Make a new instance of user 
    userDictionary.Add(u.id, user);
}
```

Also you should definitely use parameters for your query:

```
 WHERE u.company_code = @CompanyCode";
```

And finally I don't think it should be the responsibility of this code to construct dictionaries for holding addresses and phone numbers. The User constructor should take care of that.

Comment: I ended up updating what you suggested, wasnt the solution but I think your suggestion makes sense. I think I did find the problem though, the property address_id in the Address class should have been just "id"...it wasnt matching the database so I think thats why it was failing

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I must have 50 rep to add a comment, so I'll make this an answer.

Are all the fields in the DB concerning phone and address non-nullable? If no, then the mistake could be that it can't match them with your C# classes. In this case, declare immutable types nullable so that they match DB types. Like this:

```
int? val;
```